# What's the difference between single vector and vector overrides?

Tags: ios

With Xcode6+, I use pdf for vector assets, I saw two options about vector settings, there're `Single Vector` and `Vector With Overrides`, see:

[image]

I googled it but can't find any useful result. I wonder that what's the difference between single vector and vector overrides?

Comment: AFAIK "Vector with Overrides" Supports both bitmap and vectors.